# Procurve 5400 10GB

Tags: hp-procurve, 10gbethernet

I need some help for 10GB connection. I actually have a Procurve 5400zl series with some port SFP+ on V2 version module. We desperately need to connect a server with pci-x slot.
what can I do to have a 10gb link? 
If possible I'd like to use existing HW on the switch side (mean SFP+), but I'm suspecting SFP+ DAC (with a SFP+ server adapter) won't work.

Comment: There's no reason this configuration couldn't work, but you'd have to find a 10GbE PCI-X NIC w/ SPF+; good luck with *that*. I've seen PCIe NICs out there, and people connecting them just as you describe, but PCI-X is a dying standard in supported server gear.

Answer (score 2):

If you've just got a standard 10Gbps SFP+ (i.e. HP P/N: J9150A) then all you need to do is install a 10Gbps NIC inside your server. Unfortunately PCI-X is a very old standard now and the crossover between it's use and the advent of 10Gbps NICs was very small so there's not many adapters out there.

That said Intel did produce a part called a "PXLA8591SR" which was a PCI-X adapter with a 10Gbps LC SR optics that'd connect just fine to your server. You may struggle to find them out there but try eBay and other places as I found [one](http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/INTEL-PRO-10GBE-SR-SERVER-NETWORK-ADAPTER-CARD-PCI-X-PXLA8591SR-Fiber-LC-Duplex-/110757197315?_trksid=p4340.m185&_trkparms=algo=DLSL%252BSIC.NPJS&its=I&itu=UCI%252BUA&otn=10&pmod=370541224896%252B370541224896&po=&ps=63&clkid=5488449046599598918#ht_538wt_1141) in the uk.

Comment: I can confirm the HP Switches are quite happy with the 10Gb link Chopper describes; I have a college campus full of them.

Comment: there was a mistake, I was meaning PCI-E, not X. Does someone have a lan adapter model to give me? The server is a win2008r2 sbs. Thanks

Comment: Ah - well in that case there are LOTS of options, something like one of these would be ideal; http://ark.intel.com/products/39773/Intel-Ethernet-Server-Adapter-X520-SR1

Comment: ok thanks, but I need to connect by DAC cable (sfp+-sfp+). Is it possible?